# AWK Compare Column 1 from Two Files Print append column to third in output

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, array, associative-array

Looking to compare the first column of two input files that have an identical format.  The format looks like the following:

```
FILE1:
0000abc5abc3 GR096
0000def5ae87 GR001
0000cab5aea3 GR001
0000bac5aeeb GR001
0000fed5af13 GR001
0000efd5b16f GR001
0000cba5b187 GR001
0000bca5b2a3 GR001

FILE2:
0000abc5abc3 GR097
0000def5ae87 GR001
0000cab5aea3 GR001
0000bac5aeeb GR001
0000fed5af13 GR123
0000cba5b187 GR169
```

Column 1 contains MAC addresses in both FILE1 and FILE2.  I want the value of column 1 in FILE1 to check against column 1 in FILE2 and if there is a match to output the value of column 1 and column 2 of FILE1 and the value of column 2 in FILE2 as a third column in this fashion.

```
DESIRED OUTPUT:
0000abc5abc3 GR096 GR097
0000def5ae87 GR001 GR001
0000cba5b187 GR001 GR169
```

Each file contains several million entries.  Running the input in bash is eternally slow and inefficient using while loops as it loops through each entry:

```
while read -r mac1 code1; do
    while read -r mac2 code2 ; do
        if [ "$mac1" == "$mac2" ]; then
            printf "%s %s %s\n" "$mac1" "$code1" "$code2"
        fi
    done < "$FILE1"
done < "$FILE2" > OUTPUTFILE
```

Awk is significantly faster for me using arrays but I am unable to print that 2nd column of FILE2 into the third column of the output using syntax like the following.  This syntax just prints column 2 a second time:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { n[$1] = $1; n[$2] = $2; next } ($1 in n) { print n[$1],n[$2],$2 }'
```

My preference is AWK, but if it can be run in bash just as fast, I am okay with that as well.

Summary:
If the value in Column 1 in file1 is found in file2, print the value of column 1, column 2 (File1) and column2 (File2).

Comment: Don't you just want `awk 'NR==FNR { n[$1] = $2; next } ($1 in n) { print $1,n[$1],$2 }'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the output can be sorted:

```
join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Comment: +1 You beat me by 14 sec on this ;-) Add some explanation and I delete my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just to correct your awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { n[$1]=$0;next } ($1 in n) { print n[$1],$2 }' file1 file2

#Output:
0000abc5abc3 GR096 GR097 
0000def5ae87 GR001 GR001 
0000cab5aea3 GR001 GR001 
0000bac5aeeb GR001 GR001 
0000fed5af13 GR001 GR123 
0000cba5b187 GR001 GR169
```

Comment: @drfunkenstein Welcome. You can mark only one answer as solution, not all of them

Answer (score 0):

`join` is the proper tool for this:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Since it works on sorted files, I am using bash's process substitution (`<(...)`) to sort each file before feeding them to `join`.